# GWT - HTTPServlet POST Request not called

Tags: java, http, servlets, gwt

I hope there are still some GWT developers ... I'm new to GWT development and I'm trying to do a form-based file upload system.
To do so, I implemented a HTTPServlet and overrode the methode doPost.
However, when I submit the form, I do get a response 200 without any content. But if you look at my file below, I'm sending a 500 response ... And thee System.out.println is not being called ...

I went through a lot of already asked questions on the web but couldn't find a solution ...

[POST method not called on servlet - GWT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686929/post-method-not-called-on-servlet-gwt-project)

[servlet not working in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466206/servlet-not-working-in-gwt)

[How exactly servlet Work in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294016/how-exactly-servlet-work-in-gwt)

Here are files I have:

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileupload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myCompany.FileUpload
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileupload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myModule/fileupload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**FormPresenter.java** (I'm using MVP Architecture)

```
formPanel.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "fileupload");
formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
```

**FileUpload.java** (Servlet File)

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("fileupload")
public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("FileUpload doPost");
        resp.sendError(500);
    }
}
```

**Form.ui.xml**

```
<g:FormPanel ui:field="formPanel">
    <g:VerticalPanel>
        <g:FileUpload ui:field="fileUpload"></g:FileUpload>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:FormPanel>
```

Thanks for your help !

Hyukchan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I actually found the problem in my code ...
I had a filter defined with a general url pattern

**web.xml**

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

which was called before my servlet and I forgot to use :

**MyFilter.java**

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

to call the rest of filters and servlet...

Thanks for your help though Andrei !

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("fileupload")`. You already set your mapping in web.xml.